# Facebook app country restriction

Tags: facebook-apps, restriction, country

Read two posts about this without a confirmed reply. How is facebook detecting the country? Is from user's registered profile or from the IP they access facebook.com

Answer (score 0):

Facebook detects the country in a number of ways (no particular order):

- Browser language
- Language you've selected on Facebook
- IP address
- Profile details

It really depends on what you need this information for...

You should use [Facebook's App-Level Restriction settings](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/userrestrictions/) to limit your app to specific countries.

Comment: thanks! I want to restrict my app to a certain country, residents of that country. Restriction should be based on from where the user accesses the app and not by profile or language or browser.

Comment: You should use the App-Level restrictions to do this: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/userrestrictions/, or do it manually by using a IP-geolocation service.